# Can't print the value in MyType constructed using typedef probably in C

Tags: c, printing, struct, typedef

I want to create a print method to print out the int and string value in MyType.
However it only work for doIt1. How do I modify the print method, Can anyone help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct {
    int i;
    char s[1024];
} MyType;

doIt1(MyType *mt, int ii, char *ss){
    mt->i=ii;
    strcpy(mt->s, ss);
}

doIt2(MyType mt, int ii, char *ss){
    mt.i=ii;
    strcpy(mt.s, ss);
}

void print(MyType mt){
     print("%d\n", mt.i);
     print("%s\n", mt.s);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    MyType mt1, mt2;
    doIt1(&mt1, 12, "Other Stuff");
    doIt2(mt2, 7, "Something");
    print(mt1); // print out mt1
    print(mt2); // print out mt2
}
```

Comment: Why would it work for doIt2? You're passing a copy, not a pointer.

Comment: Do you know what does `MyType *mt` and `MyType mt` signify? or what are the differences?

Comment: You asked essentially the same question yesterday.  You need to read up on what it means to pass by value.

Comment: I know that doIt2 pass a copy of mt2, so the original mt2 didn't change. But i don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

In `doit2`, you are passing `mt` *by value*, that is, you are making a copy.

Inside the `doit2` function, `mt` is not an alias for `mt2`: it is another variable which will be thrown away when `doit2` exits.

Simply put, when you call

```
doIt2(mt2, 7, "Something");
```

Your code will do something like this (simplifying):

```
{
    MyType mt2_tmp = mt2;
    /* execute doIt2 passing the copy, mt2_tmp, to the function */
    doIt2(mt2_tmp, 7, "Something");
    /* the function exits and the copy is thrown away */
}
```

Comment: Its like what ever changes you are doing here will be reflected only inside the function. The original will not be changed at all.

Comment: Ya, so there's no way to print it out after if I don't change doIt2?

Comment: No, you have to use `doit1`, that is, pass your variable by reference.